# Validating two dates in acrobat javascripts

Tags: date, acrobat

well the code I posted below all works perfectly except for a small detail. When I input today date in the field dateEntered, the later rejects it, it validates if the date entered is before todays date, validate if the date falls on a weekends, but it also show an error message when it is todays date.  Actually the user should be able to enter Today or after date.

Anyone can tell me where am wrong, already tried every possible ways but still not working even the ( ==) or (===) or (<=) ..nothing

```
if (event.value!="") 
{
var e = util.scand("ddd, dd.mmm.yy", event.value);
var a = (e.getTime()) < (new Date().getTime());

if (a)  { 
app.alert("The Date cannot be before Today's Date", 1);
event.rc = null; 
}

if (e.getDay()==6 || e.getDay()==0) {
app.alert("Cannot take permission on a Weekend!", 2);
event.rc=null;
}


}
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution to my problem, I had to set the hour to 0. Thank to the one who updated this on stackoverflow and sorry forget to retain your name.

```
if (event.value!="") 
{
var e = util.scand("ddd, dd.mmm.yy", event.value);
var b=new Date();
b.setHours(0,0,0,0);

if (e<b)  { 
app.alert("ERROR: Date cannot be before"+" "+ new Date(b), 5);
event.rc = null; 
}

if (e.getDay()==6 || e.getDay()==0) {
app.alert("ALERT: The date you entered ("+event.value+") falls on a WEEKEND!", 3);
event.rc=null;
}

}
```

This codes also contains a condition of removing one weekend from the dates since the number of leaves allowed to take ranges from 1 to 7 thus only one weekend is remove.